# Change specific parameter on URL based on dropdown selection usinJavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created 2 dropdown selections like below

```
function selectCar(obj){
    var urlString = "/";
    var selectedCar = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex];
    if (selectedCar.value != "nothing"){
            window.location = window.location + selectedCar.value;
    }
}


<select name="selectcar1" onchange="selectCar(this)">
<option value="1234">audi</option>
<option value="3256">bmw</option>
<option value="7890">mercedes</option>
</select>


<select name="selectcar2" onchange="selectCar(this)">
<option value="5461">mazda</option>
<option value="3578">renault</option>
<option value="1247">ferrari</option>
</select>
```

in order to edit the parameters of this url based on the selections.

`example.com/compare?car1=1740&car2=1684`

So, if the user chooses a car from `selectcar1` the car1 in url is changed, and when the `selectcar2` is changed, the car2 is affected.

I currently add the new value into the url, I am not replacing the specific variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location = some/url;` immediately redirects request to that new URL. If you want to *compare* that is have two (or more) parameters then you have to wait until these parameters have been received.
Also `location` object has a number of properties namely `protocol`, `host`, `pathname`, `search`, and more.
So for the OP the script may look like this.

```js
var car1 = 0;
var car2 = 0;

function selectCar(obj) {
  if (obj.name === 'selectcar1')
    car1 = obj.value;
  else
    car2 = obj.value;
  if (car1 && car2) { // both are > 0
    var newUrl = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '?car1=' + car1 + '&car2=' + car2;
    console.log(newUrl);
    //location = newUrl;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="selectcar1" onchange="selectCar(this)">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1234">audi</option>
  <option value="3256">bmw</option>
  <option value="7890">mercedes</option>
</select>


<select name="selectcar2" onchange="selectCar(this)">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="5461">mazda</option>
  <option value="3578">renault</option>
  <option value="1247">ferrari</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) simplifies this.

By passing in the current page href you can set or update params while maintaining the existing ones

```
function selectCar(sel){

    var url = new URL(location.href);

    if(sel.value){
      url.searchParams.set(sel.id, sel.value)
      window.location.search = url.search
    }
}
```

Note I added id to selects : `<select id="car1" onchange="selectCar(this)"/>`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RiftE4rmDISJMkIMKtZo?p=preview)**</kbd>